# How do I set rails to use different paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nginx

I am using Rails 3 and I am proxying my app through nginx to a subdirectory, such as /pdfs/, now the stylesheets are linking from /assets/, How can I link them from /pdfs/assets/?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/pdf"` in environments.rb and start your server normally.

Then Rails will prepend `/pdf` to all your routes

Comment: Where should I put that? environments.rb is a nonexistant file, and adding it to environment.rb throws an error.

Comment: I'm just about to statically link my CSS. Is that safe?

Comment: Try `environments/production.rb` or `environments/development.rb`. Why do you want to statically link your CSS? In Rails 3.1 you should be using the asset pipeline.

Comment: Well, does the asset pipeline support sub-directories? I am proxying this app via Nginx. And, I have NO idea how to use the asset pipeline.